# Subscribing to /rosout topic

Tags: ros, rosout, rosconsole, subscribe, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way I can write a node to subscribe the log messages from the /rosout topic and save in a HTML file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266707/subscribing-to-/rosout-topic/) by [robo_ninja](https://answers.ros.org/users/27502/robo_ninja/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2017-07-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That should be pretty easy to do in Python (and only slightly more difficult in C++). For the subscription part, you can start with the [subscriber example](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29), but adapt it to subscribe to [rosgraph_msgs/Log](http://docs.ros.org/api/rosgraph_msgs/html/msg/Log.html) messages on `/rosout_agg` instead of `std_msgs/String` messages on `/chatter`. There's some more details about rosout on [the wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/rosout). For the file writing part, you can either use an XML or HTML writer in Python (a search engine will turn up many) or use regular file I/O and hand-code the HTML.

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2